# How to fill field in entity with information from its parent entity after persisting a new entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity()
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    ...

}
```

```
@Entity()
public class Child {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private long parent_id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    ...

}
```

The `Child` entity must always have a `Parent` entity.

I want the `Child` class to have the parent_id as a field and a Parent object with all the fields from its parent.

This way I can save a `Child` entity having only the id of the `Parent` and, ideally, the parent object inside the `Child` would be filled when retrieving a `Child` from the database.

I have achieved that when retrieving a `Child` from the database the parent field is filled with the `Parent` entity, but if I persist a new `Child` entity with only the parent_id, the parent object is not filled automatically.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Remove the parent_id field (and the insertable and updatable attributes). When you have only a parentId and want the corresponding parent, use EntityManager.find() or EntityManager.getReference() to get it.

Comment: @RabidOrange what do you mean under `the parent object is not filled automatically`? If you want persist the `Parent` when you persist a new `Child` you should add `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` to the `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: @SternK Lets say i have a Parent in the database like `Parent id = 1, name = "papa"`. Then I create a Child object like `Child id = null, parent_id = 1, parent = null, name = "boy"`. When I run `childRepository.save(child)` the output child that the save method produces is like this: `Child id = 1, parent_id = 1, parent = null, name = "boy"` and I want to know if it's possible to retrieve `Child id = 1, parent_id = 1, parent = Parent(id = 1, name = "papa"), name = "boy"` instead

Comment: @JBNizet I can't get rid of the parent_id field because I have some methods to find by child entities by the parent id. Then the ChildRepository throws an exception because for example a method like `.findAllByParentId(long)` can't be processed since there is no `parent_id` field

Comment: Then fix that repository method so that it uses the correct query. You can do that. It's the correct, canonical mapping.

Comment: @RabidOrange How do you know that the `parent_id = 1`? Do you have the `Parent` entity at your persistent context at this moment?

Comment: @SternK Yes this is assuming a `Parent` entity is already in the database

Comment: @RabidOrange The [persistence context](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc) and the database are the different notions.

Comment: @JBNizet I've removed the `parent_id` and only left the `parent` field removing the `insertable = false, updatable = false`. Also changed the `findAllByParentId(long)` to `findAllByParent(Parent)` to avoid errors when running the application, but the problem is still there for me. When I try to save a `Child (id = null, parent = Parent(id = 1, name = null), name = "boy")` the resulting child object after the save is this `Child(id = 1, parent = Parent(id = 1, name = null), name = "boy")`, so i can't get the Parent name (assuming there was an entity already in the database) after saving a child

Comment: So you created a Parent and assigned its ID to 1, instead of doing what I explained: get the Parent using find() or getReference()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-get-reference) should help.

If you want provide correct reference between the `Child` and the `Parent` entities and postpone the real loading of the `Parent` entity. You should do something like that:

```java
  Child newChild = new Child();
  newChild.setParent(entityManager.getReference(Parent.class, parent_id));
  // ...
  entityManager.persist(newChild);
```

Or if you want to have the `newChild` with completely initialized `Parent` instead of `entityManager.getReference` you should use `entityManager.find(Parent.class, parent_id)`.

P.S. The same advice was given by @JBNizet in comments.